# I do not get my message cUrl from firebase in your console

Tags: php, android, firebase

Good morning, I have this code that shows to send notifications of Firebase, and the code is functional and side of Android if I get the messages, but I would like to add that message cUrl php apararezca in the Firebird console, as for see how many people saw it

```
public function firebase(){

        $apiKey = "awudaw:adwdawfag-xxxxxxxx";
        $data = array('body'=>'Hola a todos tercero','title'=>'Tiene un nuevo mensaje global tercero');
        $fields = array("to"=>"/topics/tipi",'notification'=>$data);
        $headers = array('Authorization: key='.$apiKey,'Content-Type: application/json');

        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($result,true);
    }
```

Comment: Do not switch `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` off. It could be a security risk.

Comment: Is that if I activate it, the JSON does not return anything in the localhost.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software

Comment: @mypetlion My question is how to make the notification sent by cURL appear in the panel / console of notifications of firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is impossible what I want to do, after much research in forums.